# Rails create method failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create "group posts" that are connected to a "user group" and a user. The first line of my create method is failing with this error:

```
Couldn't find UserGroup with 'id'=
```

I've been looking at blog building tutorials thinking that my "group post" is acting like a comment but instead of being attached to an article it's attached to a "user group".

I'm pretty new to Rails so it could be simply a syntax issue. Any advise would be appreciated.

Here is the group post create method:

```
def create
    @user_group = UserGroup.find(params[:user_group_id])
    @group_post = current_user.group_posts.new(group_post_params)
    if @group_post.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to user_group_path(@user_group), notice: "Group Post created!"}
        end
    else
        redirect_to user_group_path(@user_group), notice: "Something went wrong."
    end
end

private

    def group_post_params
        params.require(:group_post).permit(:content, :post_type, :user_group_id)
    end
```

Here is the user group model:

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :group_members, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :members, through: :group_members, source: :user

    has_many :group_posts, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates :searchable, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}

    def owners
        members.includes(:group_members).where('group_members.owner = ?', true)
    end

    def regular_users
        members.includes(:group_members).where('group_members.owner = ?', false)
    end

end
```

Here is the group post model:

```
class GroupPost < ActiveRecord::Base

    include PublicActivity::Model
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :user_group

    validates :user_id, :presence => true
    validates :content, :presence => true

end
```

And finally the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}

  root 'pages#home'

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy, :accept] do
    member do
        put :accept
    end
  end

  resources :posts, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  resources :group_posts, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  resources :activities, only: [:index] do
    member do
      put "upvote" =>"activities#upvote"
    end
  end

  resources :user_groups do
    resources :group_posts
    resources :group_members
  end

end
```

Here is the form partial submitting the group post:

```
<div class="posts-panel">
    <%= form_for(@group_post) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'partials/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new post...", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.select :post_type, [['Request', 'request'],['Report', 'report']], {}, {class: "form-control"}  %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= hidden_field_tag :user_group_id, @usergroup.id %>
            <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Complete Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"thkRQYNcl+ySSoWIE83V22DEqYdttg+TF4coFsmasXkt2mylgB2YG/vAl2KYRey/djTqL5iNSTIyWJpsSWyCQQ==", "group_post"=>{"content"=>"This is it", "post_type"=>"prayer"}, "user_group_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Post", "controller"=>"group_posts", "action"=>"create"}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the view because *create* method is not receiving an *user_group_id* param. Please, show your view code.

Comment: I've added the form partial that submits a new group post. The view is huge and this seems to be the only relevant code.

Comment: In what line are you sending the required *:user_group_id* param?

Comment: I thought that was picked up from the url. Do I need to add that as a hidden field?

Comment: Well, you can see the parameters received in the log of your application. If it isn't passed that param, you'll need to do it as a hidden field, for example. Have a look to rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the hidden form field and when I view source it's there and working. I also added user_group_id to the group_post_params. It's still not putting it in the record however, it's nill.

Comment: Are you sure that `user_group_id` is at the base level of your params hash? Usually because of the nesting it would be something more like `params[:group_post][:user_group_id]`

Comment: @omnikron, well my url looks like http://localhost:3000/user_groups/1 where 1 is the id of the user group.

Comment: In that case wouldn't it be more likely that the user group's id would be in `params[:id]`? Can you show the entire contents of `params`? EDIT also bear in mind that the URL where you _visit_ the page with the form on it is not the same as the URL to which the form gets _submitted_, which is generated by the `form_for(@group_post)` in your view - it is most likely simply a POST to /group_post - you should be able to see this in your logs when submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks @omnikron, I've added the complete content of params to the bottom of my question. "user_group_id" is there.

Comment: You will run into minor issues like this pretty often. As a general problem solving strategy, I would include `pry-rails` in your Gemfile (development only) and put a `binding.pry` right before the failing line (UserGroup.find in this case). Then, you can stop execution at that point inspect the params hash and see if the key you're looking for is in there, and how to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Andy, I've added that gem and it shows that the user_group_id is there. I'm totally confused. lol

Comment: When you are debugging using pry, what do these two expressions return? 1.`params[:user_group_id]` 2. `UserGroup.find(params[:user_group_id])`

Comment: Omnikron, you were on the right track. I had to add @ group_post.user_group = @ user_group to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user_group_id was not inside the params hash. Adding the following line to the create method solved the issue:

```
@group_post.user_group = @user_group
```